# Can we always find a bump function on a smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, continuity

Sometimes when I am going through a proof in differnetinal geometry notes, 
they say something like: 
Let $U \subseteq V \subseteq M$, $M$ is a smooth manifold,
where $\bar{U} \subseteq V$. Then we let $h \in C^{\infty}(M)$ such that 
$h = 1$ on $\bar{U}$ and support of $h$ is contained in $V$. I was just wondering how do we know that such $h$ always exist? Thank you.

Comment: This should follow from the existence of a partition of unity on $V$, since it is a submanifold, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity

Comment: I think for a partition of unity you would need to say that $\exists$ $U, V$ rather than it working $\forall$ $U, V$ e.g. for $\overline{U}=V$ I doubt it would be $C^\infty$

Comment: $V $ should be open.

Comment: You should be able to find a proof by searching for something like "smooth Urysohn lemma".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has a open cover $M=V \cup (M\setminus \bar{U})$. Now take a partition of unity subordinate to this cover, which then can be choosen as two functions $\phi, \psi: M \rightarrow [0,1]$, where $\text{supp}(\phi)\subseteq V$, $\text{supp}(\psi) \subseteq M \setminus\bar{U}$. Then $\phi|_{\bar{U}}=1$ in order to achieve $\psi +\phi =1$. Then $\phi$ is your desired function $h$.